# plotting energy generation rate in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to make a graph for my astronomy homework in which I plot the energy generation rate of the proton-proton chain divided by density vs. the temperature. I have the equation:

```
q/rho = ((2.4 * 10**(4))* X**(2))/T9**(2/3) * exp(-3.38/T9**(1/3))

where: X**2 = the mass fraction squared = 0.5041

T9 = temperature/10**9
```

the only thing that changes is T9, everything else is a constant.
Now I've tried to plot this in gnuplot but I always get just a straight line. I've adjusted the ranges and used logscale but it always shows a straight line.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! From the [gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnuplot/info) tag description: *"Use this tag for questions about programmatic use of Gnuplot; debugging interactive usage is off-topic."* If you use it programmatically, please show us your code. We can't help with code that we don't see. See [MCVE] for guidance. If you don't use it programmatically, then your question is offtopic here, as Stackoverflow is for programming questions. In that case you might find a more fitting Q&A community on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites), or elsewhere entirely.

Answer (score 2):

gnuplot requires a decimal point to indicate where a number is to be treated as a floating point quantity rather than an integer.  So 2/3 is zero but 2./3. is 0.6666... and so on.